# How to create a secure database for each user in asp web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a web application in Visual Studio 2010 which will later be deployed on the cloud. Each user will enter data into a database and then the application will create a chart. The data is then deleted and the database of one user shouldn't be seen or modified by another user.

Is it possible to build this type of application?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is authorization and authentication. Microsoft has good tutorials about this topic. At least, it is enough to start. You can find them [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security).